# Recommended way to deal with the search autocomplete logic (server vs client)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I cannot decide between placing all the possible entries in the client at page generation and then letting the client do the filtering or asking the server at each button click to update the typeahead list.

I would love to go with the former option, but surely, if there are too many entries in my database this would become counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I lean towards putting it on the server. But it depends. Here is my thought process.

- Putting the list on the server allows for a single place to maintain the list items.
- Server side / database logic can restrict the number of entries returned (i.e. `SELECT TOP X`)
- From my experiences, the autocomplete request and response is very quick for a large amount of data (< 1 sec and could probably be less if the database is properly setup).
- Page loading times can be reduced by only getting data when a user needs it as opposed to loading all of the data up front.